# parse_str problems

Tags: php

I’m sorting a list and using [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to update a database. I need help parsing the string. This is the query string that I need to parse:

```
images_list[]=32&images_list[]=95&images_list[]=97&images_list[]=96&images_list[]=102&images_list[]=103&images_list[]=99&images_list[]=101&images_list[]=98&john=hi
```

I have put john=hi to test to see if the string is actually being sent via Ajax to the *processor.php* file. I am able to get the variable john=hi from the URL, so the query string is being sent perfectly fine. This is my code so far, but I can't seem to access the data I need, it appears as if nothing is there:

```
<?php
    // Connect to the database
    require_once('connect.php');

    parse_str($_GET['images_list']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($images_list); $i++) {
        $id = $images_list[$i];
        mysql_query("UPDATE images SET ranking = '$i' WHERE id = '$id'");
        echo $images_list[$i];
    }
?>
```

Comment: You can use foreach($array as $key=>$value) instead of a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_GET['images_list']` is an array of integers. There's nothing to parse there. PHP already did it for use. So, skip the `parse_str` part and easily use `$_GET['images_list']` instead of `$images_list`.

Whole code:

```
<?php
    //Connect to DB
    require_once('connect.php');

    foreach ($_GET['images_list'] as $i => $id) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE images SET ranking = " .
                    mysql_real_escape_string($i) .
                    " WHERE id = " .
                    mysql_real_escape_string($id));
        echo $id;
    }
?>
```